# C# how to notify clients about server dynamic ip update

Tags: c#, networking

I have a chat application server running on a PC which has dynamic IP.
nearly every hour it keeps changing.

how can i notify the users abt the changed IP?

Comment: can you use something like dyndns to avoid this problem?

Comment: Does the hostname stay the same?

@jasper I don't think dyndns provides that service for free anymore. I'm not even sure if they provide that service at all anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In native code you can do this using [NotifyIpInterfaceChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa814450%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - not sure whether this is usable via P/Invoke, as it uses a callback.  This supports both IPV6 and IPV4.

You would then need to act appropriately to notify the users.

Prior to Windows Vista, the equivalent (IPV4 only) is [NotifyAddrChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366329%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).